# Output readfile image to HTML

Tags: php, html

How can I display the outputted file in an HTML? Provided the script is like this

```
function function_image($url) {
    $file = file_get_contents($url);
    $type = 'image/jpeg';
    header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
}
```

How do I display it in html? Do I need to place it in an **src** attribute? or just echo it?

```
<img src="<?php echo function_image('http://otherwebsite.com/image.jpeg'); ?>" />

or 

<?php echo function_image('http://otherwebsite.com/image.jpeg'); ?>
```

Comment: where is the `function_image()` method and how is it used?

Comment: Did you try simple `<img src="<?php echo $file; ?>" />` ?

Comment: @J.Litvak I'm trying to hide the exact url of the image. Kinda like proxy serving an image; So basically I just pass the url on the function and the function retrieve the content and render it on html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're using to output the image would be its own *page*, not just a function you call.  For example, let's call it **image.php**:

```
<?php
$file = '../image.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
?>
```

Then in your HTML you would reference `image.php` as though it were an image, since that's exactly what it outputs:

```
<img src="image.php" />
```

HTTP doesn't care about things like "file types", there are just headers and data.  **image.php** returns an image header (`Content-Type:image/jpeg`) and image data, so as far as the browser is concerned it's an image "file".

Comment: Can I use a function instead of the php file itself?

Comment: @MadzmarUllang: You can encapsulate the code in a function if you really want to.  But the main point is that the entire output of that PHP script would be just the image (and its associated headers, of course).  It's a separate HTTP request than the HTML page, just like any other image.

Comment: One last question. How do I load an external image?

Comment: @MadzmarUllang: By "external image" do you mean that you want your code to fetch an image from elsewhere on the internet and return that?  It's pretty similar.  You could use something like `cURL` to fetch the image from the external source and then output it.  Saving it to a local file and then using `readfile()` like you already do seems pretty straightforward.  I imagine you could do the same thing without saving it to the file system, perhaps using the output from `cURL` or `file_get_contents()` and writing it directly to the script's output.  I haven't tested it.